# What is the meaning of the abbreviation id(x,y)

Tags: integration, differential-forms, integral-domain

In the subject of the change of variables via integration of 2-forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a function $\omega=f(x,y) dx \wedge dy$ over $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, the teacher says that we go from a domain $id(x,y)$ to a domain $(x,y)$. And by what he says, that symbol  $id(x,y)$ seems to be called - a point "identity" thing that goes to another point $(x,y)$. Can someone tell me what that "$id(x,y)$" really mean.

Here is the link to the [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXL_0X1vMT0&list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7&index=13) video and look at it at 3:16 minutes at the "trivial parametrization". Thank you in advance for your patience with a physicist that never saw that abbreviation but who is learning something absolutely fantastic.
Mario

Comment: The map $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y)$?

Comment: "from a domain $\text{id}(x,y)$" is incorrect. We have a mapping (function) from one domain to another.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

It's the identity function on $D$.   It's a function $id : D \to D$ defined as $id(x,y) = (x,y)$

He's using it to show how the change of variable works for a trivial case.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I should have guessed that.